# Onclick an element, sliding toggle of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do an accordian style opening/closing of div using jquery. But for some reason the next() in jquery doesn't seem to be working. I want when a title is clicked, all other div should be closed except the clicked one.

Html code --

```
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
</div>
<div class="office">sadasd</div>
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
</div>
<div class="office">sadasd</div>
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
</div>
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/v3hc19np/1/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Include complete code here. See **[mcve]**

Comment: The `h3` elements have no siblings, hence `next()` finds nothing

Comment: I added parent() before next. Now it slides down but slides up again as I want all other divs to be closed. I may need to change the html?

Comment: Fixed -- https://jsfiddle.net/v3hc19np/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others said, there is no `$.next('div')` adjacent to the titles, so I moved `.office` in so that that element is now adjacent to it. Updated with your original HTML.

```js
$(function() {
  var $titles = $('.office-title'),
      $offices = $('.office');
  $titles.on('click', function() {
    var $target = $(this).parent('.office-row').next('.office');
    $target.slideToggle();
    $offices.not($target).slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
.office {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
</div>
<div class="office">sadasd</div>
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
</div>
<div class="office">sadasd</div>
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
</div>
<div class="office">sadasd</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Is it possible to achieve this without changing the html structure. I did but it's not working perfectly.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra sure it's possible, but why would you want to? It will just change the JS a little, but nothing major. If you're having trouble implementing now, I doubt using the original HTML will change anything.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra updated the code with your original HTML

Comment: Actually in my original html structure the accordian header starts with span and I cannot put div inside the span.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Your div was not nested correctly, thus the next('div') could not be found. Here's how it should be:

```
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
  <div class="office">sadasd</div>
</div>
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
  <div class="office">sadasd</div>
</div>
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
  <div class="office">sadasd</div>
</div>
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/v3hc19np/5/

Answer (score 0):

we can loop the elements and display them none using jquery and then use toggle function here is the working code for you query

```
 $('.office-title').click(function() {
    $(".office").each(function(index,obj){
        $(obj).hide();
    });
    $(e.target).parent().next().slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
```